# CSV update/modification

Tags: c#

Trying to override a **single** record of the following CSV:

```
PRODUCT,RECORD,ACCOUNT
100,200,300
```

using this code:

```
public static void UpdateCSV(string filePath, string stringToReplace, string updatedString)
    {
        string path = filePath;
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        if (File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(","))
                    {
                        string[] split = line.Split(',');

                        if (split[1].Contains(stringToReplace))
                        {
                            split[1] = updatedString;
                            line = string.Join(",", split);
                        }
                    }

                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
            {
                foreach (string line in lines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

But invoking the following does not make a difference ('PRODUCT' does not change to 'MYPRODUCT'):

```
UpdateCSV(@"C:\Test.csv", "PRODUCT", "MYPRODUCT");
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: As a generic suggestion: use a good c# csv reader / writer library. They are much better than your code. E.g. you are not handling " or a , in a string at all.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianSauer
CSVHelper for example does not support overriding.

Comment: @entrup You are checking only second value of line `split[1].Contains(stringToReplace)`. This static condition will bypass many values without checking. Example : "PRODUCT" is on 0th index after split.

Comment: @entrup What exactly do you want achieve. Are you going to update CSV header only OR data/records as well?

Comment: Just trying to update data/record. What needs to be added than ?

Comment: Your writer object won't actually "write" anything without calling `writer.Flush();`.

Comment: It does write and updates a single record @bolkay but I need to modify the code to cater for the entire row and additional rows